# Adding narrative to pie chart (highcharts)

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am looking to fill the space on the sides of a pie chart and I wanted to add some additional narrative to explain the information on the chart..

I know I can make the width of the chart smaller and add the narrative outside  the chart..

This is the code I have so far for generating the pie chart

```
$('.companyName').highcharts({
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: true, 
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Division'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Quarter 1 (0/17/2015 - 10/23/2015)'      
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 40,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
},  
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        showInLegend: true, 
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            },
            connectorColor: 'silver'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: '',
    data: [
        ['Department 1', 334]
        ,['Department 2', 224]
        ,['Department 3', 105]
        ,['Department 4', 19]
        ,['Department 5', 1]             
    ]
}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place additional elements into Highcharts chart you can use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) and add e.g. [text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) or [label](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.label).

```
$(function () {
    $('#companyName').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: true,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Division'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Quarter 1 (0/17/2015 - 10/23/2015)'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 40,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    },
                    connectorColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: '',
            data: [
                ['Department 1', 334],
                ['Department 2', 224],
                ['Department 3', 105],
                ['Department 4', 19],
                ['Department 5', 1]
            ]
        }]
    }, function (chart) { // on complete
        chart.renderer.label('Adding narrative to<br> pie chart (highcharts)', 250, 200, null, 100, 100)
            .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        })
            .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 6
        })
            .add();

    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxrwztaz/